# efficiency of Open MP with fortran 90?

Tags: performance, fortran, openmp

Hi all and thanks to those who will get a look to my question.

I have a subroutine which I try to use open MP to do what I want but it seems my code is faster without.
the problem I have a big list of point with coordinates (x,y) and I have two reference grid X_ref(nline,ncol) and Y_ref(nline,ncol). For each point of the list, I want the line and colonne index of the closest point reagrds to my two reference grids, knowing the distance between one point and my reference grid : dis =sqrt( (x_i - X_ref(I,J)))² + (y_i - Y_ref(I,J)² ).

the subroutine is in a module file where, it can access to the ST_OBS and ST_REF_GRID structures.
with 1 thread (I_NTASK=1) it takes 8.52527618E-02  seconds
with 16 thread (I_NTASK=16) it takes 0.126778603 seconds
for 1 point( index I_T)
there are no symetry in the reference grid that I could use to reduce it.

Why is it faster with one task ?

```
SUBROUTINE COLOC_LIST_2_REFGRID_OMP(I_T,I_NTASK,I_LIN_START,I_LIN_STOP,I_COL_START,I_COL_STOP,&
    R_MIN_DIS,I_COL_INDEX,I_LIN_INDEX)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    LOGICAL :: L_ID1,L_ID2,L_ID3,L_ID4
    INTEGER :: I_T,I_NT,I_NTASK,I_thread_id,I_LIN_START,I_LIN_STOP,I_COL_START,I_COL_STOP,I_C,I_L
    INTEGER,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:) :: IT1_COL_MIN_INDEX,IT1_LIN_MIN_INDEX
    REAL, PARAMETER :: PR_MAX_DIS=999
    REAL :: R_DIS
    REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:) :: RT1_MIN_DIS
    !OUTPUT
    INTEGER :: I_COL_INDEX,I_LIN_INDEX
    REAL :: R_MIN_DIS
    !----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! TABLES THAT STORE THE MIN INDEX BY PROCESSING TASK USING OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM
    ALLOCATE(IT1_COL_MIN_INDEX(0:I_NTASK-1))
    ALLOCATE(IT1_LIN_MIN_INDEX(0:I_NTASK-1))
    ALLOCATE(RT1_MIN_DIS(0:I_NTASK-1))
    DO I_NT=0,I_NTASK-1
        IT1_COL_MIN_INDEX(I_NT)=0
        IT1_LIN_MIN_INDEX(I_NT)=0
        RT1_MIN_DIS(I_NT)=PR_MAX_DIS
    ENDDO
    !$omp parallel &
    !$omp   shared (I_COL_START,I_COL_STOP,I_LIN_START,I_LIN_STOP) &
    !$omp   shared (IT1_COL_MIN_INDEX,IT1_LIN_MIN_INDEX,RT1_MIN_DIS) &
    !$omp   private (I_C,I_L,I_thread_id,R_DIS)
    !$omp do 
    doCOLON: DO I_C=I_COL_START,I_COL_STOP
        doLIN: DO I_L=I_LIN_START,I_LIN_STOP
            I_thread_id = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
            R_DIS=SQRT( (ST_OBS%RT1_x(I_T)-ST_REF_GRID%RT2_x(I_C,I_L))**2 + &
                        (ST_OBS%RT1_y(I_T)-ST_REF_GRID%RT2_y(I_C,I_L))**2 )
            IF (R_DIS.lt.RT1_MIN_DIS(I_thread_id)) THEN
                RT1_MIN_DIS(I_thread_id)=R_DIS
                IT1_LIN_MIN_INDEX(I_thread_id)=I_L
                IT1_COL_MIN_INDEX(I_thread_id)=I_C
            ENDIF
        ENDDO doLIN
    ENDDO doCOLON
    !$omp end do
    !$omp end parallel  

    !NOW WE GET THE MINIMUM AMONG ALL MINIMUM OF ALL THREADS 
    R_MIN_DIS=PR_MAX_DIS
    DO I_NT=0,I_NTASK-1            
        IF (RT1_MIN_DIS(I_NT).lt.R_MIN_DIS) THEN
            R_MIN_DIS=RT1_MIN_DIS(I_NT)
            I_COL_INDEX=IT1_COL_MIN_INDEX(I_NT)
            I_LIN_INDEX=IT1_LIN_MIN_INDEX(I_NT)
        ENDIF
    ENDDO

    DEALLOCATE(IT1_COL_MIN_INDEX,IT1_LIN_MIN_INDEX,RT1_MIN_DIS)
ENDSUBROUTINE COLOC_DARDAR_MSG_GRID_OMP
```

Comment: The code is quite hard to read. Please use some indentation inside each structured block or construct to make the structure visible. Also consider using whitespace inside your code lines.

Comment: Also, use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Please read the short descriptions of the tags you add to your questions.

Comment: It is very difficult to read, but *if* I do understand it why aren't you using a reduction?

Comment: It's quite easy actually to write OpenMP code that is slower than serial version, there can be many reasons for that. First of all : how many physical cores do you have on your machine? And how many iterations are you performing in the each loop ?

Comment: By the way, repeatedly calling `omp_get_thread_num()` in the inner loop is not needed. You can call it at the beginning of the outer loop, before the inner loop.

Comment: And you should swap the `doCOLON` and `doLIN` loops to get a better memory access pattern to the `%RT2_*(:,:)` arrays. This is actually true also for the serial version, but it can be even more critical for the threaded version depending on the size of the arrays. Also, please show the command line you are compiling with

Comment: You are basically looking through the set of points defined by arrays RT2_x and RT2_y for the point closest to a point (xi,yi) with memory referencing hidden in derived types. 
 OpenMP is a shared memory model where poor memory referencing is a performance killer. This is a brute force search with no consideration of cache optimisation. 1) You are not getting a good result as you are not accessing memory sequentially (swap I_C & I_l) and 2) you have no mention of any structure of the RT2_x and RT2_y arrays you might take advantage of.  Also, for how many points (xi,yi) are you searching ?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried your code to check as this isn't a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but anyway, here are a few remarks:

0. I'm assuming here that you have correctly measured your **elapsed time** and not **cpu time** using `omp_get_wtime()`. If you haven't, please do it and verify your findings.
1. Style: please please please, indent your code. I know this has nothing to do with the question at hand, but believe me, you'll make everybody (including yourself) a big favor by indenting correctly your code. Good readability is the first line of defense against bugs.
2. As already mentioned in comments by @PierU, you should swap your `doCOLON` and `doLIN` to get linear access to  `ST_REF_GRID%RT2_x` and `ST_REF_GRID%RT2_y`. This will be very beneficial for your code irrespective of the parallel aspect.
3. Also already noted by @PierU, move the call to `omp_get_thread_num()` away from the loops. It has nothing to do there. Calling it once is far sufficient for your need (actually, as you'll see, you won't even need it in the first place).
4. Remove the call to `SQRT()`. This is costly and unnecessary. Comparing distances and squares of distances, when all what you want is getting the shortest of them, is equivalent.
5. Finally, the main reason (I believe) for your observed slowdown: [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing). By using and updating your `RT1_MIN_DIS`, `I_COL_INDEX` and `J_COL_INDEX` you're constantly trashing your cache across your threads and cores. Consider rather using a reduction for this, either with per-thread variables that you reduce at the end with a `critical` section, or by defining your own user-defined `reduction` function. A quick search should point you to many good examples on how to do that.

Once you've applied all of that, please let us know of the results and of the need for further improvement.

Comment: Good point for the false sharing, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

We know nothing of the relative sizes of (I_LIN_STOP-I_LIN_START) to (I_COL_STOP-I_COL_START) to confim, but changing the DO order should be better. (you did say a big list)

The following code changes could demonstrate some recommendations and an improved performance, hopefully with better cache usage.

```
 SUBROUTINE COLOC_LIST_2_REFGRID_OMP (I_T,I_NTASK,I_LIN_START,I_LIN_STOP,I_COL_START,I_COL_STOP,  &
                                      R_MIN_DIS,I_COL_INDEX,I_LIN_INDEX)

    IMPLICIT NONE
  !INPUT
    INTEGER :: I_T, I_NTASK, I_LIN_START,I_LIN_STOP, I_COL_START,I_COL_STOP
  !OUTPUT
    REAL    :: R_MIN_DIS
    INTEGER :: I_COL_INDEX,I_LIN_INDEX

  !LOCAL
    REAL, PARAMETER :: PR_MAX_DIS=999.**2
    REAL,   DIMENSION(0:I_NTASK) :: RT1_MIN_DIS
    INTEGER,DIMENSION(0:I_NTASK) :: IT1_COL_MIN_INDEX, IT1_LIN_MIN_INDEX
    INTEGER :: I_thread_id,I_C,I_L, ml,mc
    REAL    :: R_DIS, mdis, xt,yt

    !----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! TABLES THAT STORE THE MIN INDEX BY PROCESSING TASK USING OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM
    RT1_MIN_DIS       = PR_MAX_DIS
    IT1_LIN_MIN_INDEX = 0
    IT1_COL_MIN_INDEX = 0

    xt = ST_OBS%RT1_x(I_T)
    yt = ST_OBS%RT1_y(I_T)

    !$omp parallel do &
    !$omp   shared (I_COL_START,I_COL_STOP, I_LIN_START,I_LIN_STOP, xt,yt) &
    !$omp   shared (IT1_COL_MIN_INDEX, IT1_LIN_MIN_INDEX, RT1_MIN_DIS) &
    !$omp   private (I_C,I_L,I_thread_id, R_DIS, mdis,mc,ml)

    doLIN: DO I_L = I_LIN_START,I_LIN_STOP

        I_thread_id = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM ()
        mdis        = RT1_MIN_DIS(I_thread_id)
        ml          = IT1_LIN_MIN_INDEX(I_thread_id)
        mc          = IT1_COL_MIN_INDEX(I_thread_id)

        doCOLON: DO I_C = I_COL_START,I_COL_STOP
            R_DIS =   ( ( xt - ST_REF_GRID%RT2_x(I_C,I_L) )**2 + &
                        ( yt - ST_REF_GRID%RT2_y(I_C,I_L) )**2  )
            IF (R_DIS < mdis) THEN
                mdis = R_DIS
                ml   = I_L
                mc   = I_C
            ENDIF
        END DO doCOLON

        RT1_MIN_DIS(I_thread_id)       = mdis
        IT1_LIN_MIN_INDEX(I_thread_id) = mL
        IT1_COL_MIN_INDEX(I_thread_id) = mC

    END DO doLIN

    !$omp end parallel do

    !NOW WE GET THE MINIMUM AMONG ALL MINIMUM OF ALL THREADS 
    R_MIN_DIS = PR_MAX_DIS
    DO I_thread_id = 0,I_NTASK-1            
        IF (RT1_MIN_DIS(I_thread_id) < R_MIN_DIS) THEN
            R_MIN_DIS   = RT1_MIN_DIS(I_thread_id)
            I_COL_INDEX = IT1_COL_MIN_INDEX(I_thread_id)
            I_LIN_INDEX = IT1_LIN_MIN_INDEX(I_thread_id)
        ENDIF
    ENDDO
    R_MIN_DIS = sqrt ( R_MIN_DIS )

 END SUBROUTINE COLOC_LIST_2_REFGRID_OMP
```